# Android and OpenGL - See object through another object

Tags: android, opengl-es, light

I'm a total noob and I'm trying to display a little submarine I built in a 3d modeling program in opengl (Blender).

The submarine is built using a long cylinder with a sphere intersecting on the end of it.

The problem that I'm getting is that when I look at the result, I can see the entire sphere through the cylinder. I can also see the end of the cylinder through the sphere. This appears when I have lighting on. I'm using ambient and diffuse lighting. I just want to see half the sphere on the outside of the cylinder and I don't want to see any innards.

I have face culling on and it removes the front faces of both objects, but I clearly see the sphere.

Below I pasted my onSurfaceCreated function where I set up all the opengl parameters. Any suggestions are appreciated!

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    //
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    //gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHT0);

    // Define the ambient component of the first light
    float[] light0Ambient = {0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f};        
    gl.glLightfv(gl.GL_LIGHT0, gl.GL_AMBIENT, FloatBufferFromFloatArray(light0Ambient, 4));

    // Define the diffuse component of the first light
    float[] light0Diffuse = {0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 1.0f};
    gl.glLightfv(gl.GL_LIGHT0, gl.GL_DIFFUSE, FloatBufferFromFloatArray(light0Diffuse, 4));

    // Define the specular component and shininess of the first light
    float[] light0Specular = {0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 1.0f};
    float light0Shininess = 0.4f;
    //gl.glLightfv(gl.GL_LIGHT0, gl.GL_SPECULAR, FloatBufferFromFloatArray(light0Specular, 4));        

    // Define the position of the first light
    float[] light0Position = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
    gl.glLightfv(gl.GL_LIGHT0, gl.GL_POSITION, FloatBufferFromFloatArray(light0Position, 4)); 

    // Define a direction vector for the light, this one points correct down the Z axis
    float[] light0Direction = {0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f};
    //gl.glLightfv(gl.GL_LIGHT0, gl.GL_SPOT_DIRECTION, FloatBufferFromFloatArray(light0Direction, 3));

    // Define a cutoff angle. This defines a 90° field of vision, since the cutoff
    // is number of degrees to each side of an imaginary line drawn from the light's
    // position along the vector supplied in GL_SPOT_DIRECTION above
    //gl.glLightf(gl.GL_LIGHT0, gl.GL_SPOT_CUTOFF, 180.0f);

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    // which is the front? the one which is drawn counter clockwise
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);
    // which one should NOT be drawn
    gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);

    gl.glClearDepthf(10f);
    gl.glPolygonOffset(1.0f, 2);

    initShape();

    gl.glScalef(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like the normals are reversed.

Comment: http://img696.imageshack.us/i/13043028.png/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried checking to see if it's a backface culling issue? Check it by changing the `glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)` to `glDisable`, just to check it's definitely not that. It can be possible to have both winding orders on the same mesh, so culling can be right for one part of the model but wrong for another - it's easiest just to disable it to be sure that's not the issue.

It's either that or your surface may have been created without a depth buffer for some reason? Check the EGLConfig parameter to be sure that's not the case. Usually it would be created with a depth buffer by default, but it's possible to override that behaviour.

Also modelling things with internal faces which will never be seen is not going to do good things for your realtime performance. You should consider using a boolean 'or' operation in blender at least to get rid of the internal faces but ultimately it's best to craft your models with lots of care and attention to their topology, not just for poly count but also for how well they fit together into a triangle strip (that doesn't excuse the issue you're getting right now - that's just a note for the future)

Comment: I removed the face culling and got rid of the internal faces and then it looked great. I turned face culling back on and it still looked good so I figure that it must've been the internal faces. What is the EGLConfig parameter though? I don't see any good material about it on the web.

Comment: Been away for a few days. EGLConfig is a low level EGL type, and can be used by static methods like `javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGL10.eglGetConfigAttrib` to find out what your app has to work with. It's a bit of a pain to use, but really useful to know exactly what capabilities your renderer has.

Answer (score 1):

I see, that you're still thinking in terms of "initializing some scene graph". That's not how OpenGL works (gee, this is the third time in a row I write this as answer). All that stuff you've doing in onSurfaceCreated actually belong into the display routine. OpenGL is not a scene graph. You set all the state you need right before you're drawing the stuff that requires that state.

I see you've that function "initShape" there. I don't think this does what you intend.

Comment: initShape just opens a file that contains all the vertices, indexes, and normals that are used for drawing the shapes. 

So all the stuff in my onSurfaceCreated actually belongs in onDrawFrame? All the examples I've seen out there actually do it this way :). I'll go ahead and move it down so that it's all together. 

What about the sphere in the cylinder problem? Do you think that this will take care of that?

Comment: There is probably better places to load your geometry, like onStart().

There is always the possibility of multiple surfaces, so do you really want to reload the geometry for each one?

Comment: Yes, I know those tutorials. They all got it wrong. OpenGL is a state machine, which means, that you've to reset the state vector to what you need for something right before you do it, otherwise, things that happend ages ago might bite your ass. There are of course things suited one time initialization, like loading textures or filling vertex buffer objects with data. But the stuff you do in your code, including setting the viewport and projection, all belongs into the display function.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have an EGL context with the depth buffer enabled? If you are using GLSurfaceView you probably are looking for something like SimpleEGLConfigChooser(false) which should be SimpleEGLConfigChooser(true).

Comment: What is the EGL config? I've looked at the android reference but the explanation isn't that good (I actually see none at all). 

Instead of SimpleEGLConfigChooser, do you mean setEGLConfigChooser by any chance? I tried the set and it looks like it make a difference but I can't quite put my finger on what it did :). Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: From the Wiki: "EGL is an interface between [...] OpenGL ES [...] and the underlying native platform window system. It handles graphics context management, surface/buffer binding, and rendering synchronization." In other words, it provides OpenGL ES with the 'world' it lives in, including color/depth/alpha/stencil buffer sizes. If you want to know more DON'T look at GLSurfaceView source code if you want to retain your sanity :P, google for some tutorials instead.

Answer (score 1):

Lets see your onDrawFrame()? What is your projection, it could be flipped normals AND a messed up projection making it look funny.

Problems with your depth buffer or depth testing are possible too.

Edit: It looks like depth-test is not your problem, since you can see depth-culling from your the polygon that is intersecting the the sphere. It looks like your geometry is the problem.

I'd make it so your camera can move, then you can look around and figure out whats messed up with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using textures have a look at the blending function you are using. It might be the case that pixels that overlap get multiplied as in an overlay effect rather than overwritten which is what you want I suppose.